# Colorbox not opening

Tags: colorbox

I'm trying to open a google map into a colorbox lightbox, but it's not working. I have tried some solutions I have found on Google search, but none of them worked to me.

Here is the portion of my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colorbox.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
```

And then calling Colorbox...

```
 $(document).on("click", "a", function(){
   $('.link').colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"})
 });
```

Always the link opens up on the current page but Colorbox isn't shown. Here is the link for the page: http://www.atcbsb.com.br/radar.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed... I realized that links are created by datatable, so I changed the colorbox calling function to the following:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e){
         $('a.link').colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});        
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simple solution for u
just call jquery function from your anchor tag. that jquery calls colorbox.
see below example

```
//script
<script type="text/javascript">

function colorboxFunc(currentId)
{
    $("#"+currentId).colorbox({iframe:true, width:"60%", height:"100%"});
}
</script>


//html anchor tag

<a id="putHereDynamicID" href="Your Pop Page Link" onclick="colorboxFunc(this.id);" >Click Here To See Pop Up</a>
```